# Claim ownage for Google Apps on a domain that previously belonged to another Google Apps user?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

We bought a domain and it happens so that it belonged to another guy previously and this guy had Google Apps attached to it. But now it belongs to us and we would like to have our own Google Apps on it. There seems to be no way to claim it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Claiming will not be possible as nor the account nor the data in it belong to you. You should be able to make a new account.

As I have found numerous such issues on Google Product Forums (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/v6qNeyoTW3c) it seems you need to verify your domain (add either TXT or CNAME record) and contact google.

Related:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/FpirBKEwMXY
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/v6qNeyoTW3c
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/AGd6Lswe8KM/8bdNn0okSqIJ
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/3OE2n5XM5ug

Comment: We are not able, it says - "Already in Use".

Comment: I have updated the comment. You should contact google via product forums and verify the ownership of domain.